# GCP MQL: Calculate ratio from 3 metrics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-monitoring, monitoring-query-language

I have 3 metrics created in my GCP **1)** success request count **2)** redirected request count and **3)** failed request count. All the 3 metrics are created from log-based metric on Kubernetes log.

Here's basically a Terraform resource definition of one metric "Success requests.

```
resource "google_logging_metric" "success_requests" {
  filter      = <<-EOT
    resource.type="k8s_container"
    jsonPayload.message:"Request success"
  EOT
  name        = "success_requests"
  project     = var.gcp_project_id

  metric_descriptor {
    metric_kind = "DELTA"
    unit        = "1"
    value_type  = "INT64"
  }
}
```

The other 2 basically just filter `jsonPayload.message` with `Request redirected` and `Request failed`.

I want to create a dashboard that shows the success ratio with this formula

```
success_rate = success_requests / (success_requests + redirected_requests + failed_requests)
```

I am successful creating a dashboard that shows the three metrics using below MQL.

```
k8s_container | { 
    t_0:
        metric logging.googleapis.com/user/success_requests;
    t_1: 
        metric logging.googleapis.com/user/redirected_requests;
    t_2: 
        metric logging.googleapis.com/user/failed_requests
} | union
```

But how do I create a dashboard that display the success rate with formula as mentioned before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform some arithmetic operations using metrics, you need to work with the time series using [Arithmetic Computation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/examples#qlx-add-sub)

> To sum two time series, configure your query to fetch two tables of
> time series, join those results, and then call the add function. The
> following example illustrates a query that computes the sum of the
> number of bytes read from, and written to, Compute Engine instances:

```
  fetch gce_instance
  | { metric 'compute.googleapis.com/instance/disk/read_bytes_count'
    ; metric 'compute.googleapis.com/instance/disk/write_bytes_count' }
  | outer_join 0
  | add
```

After you summarize the three time series you can use [div function.](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#div-func)

The following query uses time_shift, join, and div to compute the ratio of the mean utilization in each zone between now and one week ago.

```
fetch gce_instance::compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization
| group_by [zone], mean(val())
| {
    ident
  ;
    time_shift 1w
  }
| join | div
```

You can review more examples of queries using MQL [in this Link.](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/examples)

You can review more of Functions implementing the arithmetic operators in MQL [in this link.](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#arithmetic-group)

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you need is an outer_join and not union. Note that MQL's outer_join only supports joining two metrics. But you can use two outer_join operations to join three tables as shown below.

After joining the metrics, you can simply refer to them by names like `success_requests`, `failed_requests`, etc.

Note that `outer_join 0,0` performs a full outer join on two tables and substitutes a 0 if one of the input streams doesn't have a value at a given timestamp.

Example:

```
{
  {k8s_container :: logging.googleapis.com/user/success_requests ;
   k8s_container :: logging.googleapis.com/user/redirected_requests}
  | outer_join 0,0 ;
  k8s_container :: logging.googleapis.com/user/failed_requests
} 
| outer_join 0,0
| value [success_rate: success_requests / (success_requests + redirected_requests + failed_requests)]
```

Comment: You can also use macros to factor out the common prefix: `def k8s(m) = k8s_container :: 'logging.googleapis.com/user/' $m '_requests';` And then just say `@k8s('success')` which makes the query a bit more readable. See: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/query-language#ql-macros